Customizing the exported data in react-apexcharts
I have series of over 40 elements in apexcharts of type horizontal bar, and I slice 10 of this items to show it.
The problem is when I export it as csv file that is an option built in the apexcharts library the apexcharts export only the 10 items that I show it.
So, how to till apexcharts to export entire 40 items in the file?
Note: The problem may be solved if you can till me how to limit the number of bars that be displayed in the chart without slice the series, so that I will provide the entire elements to the series of apexcharts and limit what to show from it.
